# Java script Passing a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my java script.its lace on a image and when i click the circle  it enlarges.
But when i click it again it should be the normal size again. 
See the image below..
http://i.imgbox.com/adbuiwsa.png[image]
This is the code for the javascript circle.What i need is when i click the blue circle again it should be the normal size again... How do i code it?? I preffer is it is done using a variable...Pls help me guys.

```
$('#c1').click(function () {
    clearCircle()
    ResetCircle()

    $(this).removeClass("blink1");
    //$(this).css('background-color', '#005aa8');
    $(this).css('width', '190px');
    $(this).css('height', '190px');
    $(this).css('top', 243 - ((190 - 125) / 2));
    $(this).css('left', 335 - ((190 - 125) / 2));
    $(this).css('background-image', 'URL(assets/images/blue_back.png)');
});
```

Comment: Add a counter and count the number of clicks

Comment: Did my solution below not work for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not edit your code but I have a sample that should work for you as well: http://jsfiddle.net/bGAj7/

HTML:

```
<div class="circle">
    <p>
        Rain passing through a hillside
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle{
    border:3px solid yellow;
    background-color:darkBlue;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50px;
    -webkit-border-radius:50px;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align:center;
}

.circle p{
    height:100%; 
    padding-top:10px;
}

.circle-enlarged{
    transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$('.circle').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass('circle-enlarged');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your class in the clicked element and check its state.

```
$('#c1').click(function(e) {
   var that = $(this);

   if( that.hasClass('active_circle') ) {
       that.removeClass('active_circle');
       // Reset circle to normal state
   }
   else {
       that.addClass('active_circle');
       // Resize circle
   }
});
```

Comment: Or just `$(this).toggleClass('active_circle');`.

Comment: I aded this but when i click the circle no result nothing happens, It doesnt even enlarge....

Comment: @DrekJohn can you create a jsfiddle and show me hows you implement?

Comment: @jogesh_pi http://jsfiddle.net/bGAj7/4/ I didnt add the beckgroud and the blue circle image!